# Symfony2 php.ini

Tags: php, apache, symfony

When checking with `app/check.php` `Symfony2` says this `Configuration file used by PHP : /etc/php5/cli/php.ini` however `phpinfo();` displays that Apache is using `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`.

I tried searching but couldn't find a solution. Could someone explain how do I tell my `Symfony2` app to use Apache2's `php.ini`? Or is there something obvious I am missing here?

I am new to Symfony

Comment: `app/check.php` runs using PHP CLI, and that often uses a different php.ini.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried accessing `check.php` using `Apache` then it said it's using ` /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. I think I missed the obvious ATTENTION message shown by `check.php`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP cli uses another ini than PHP apache. That happends quite often (you often also want other configuration).

When you use Symfony from both console (the commands) and apache (the app), you should make sure both ini files are correctly configured for Symfony.

In the browser, you can go to `web/config.php` to see a report of Symfony about your PHP settings and such.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu Apache uses `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and the command line uses `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`. This is related to your OS and not Symfony2.